# How to ensure you are in the homepage in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, match, location-href

There's a Greasemonkey script I run matching:

```
// @include     *://example.com/*
// @include     *://www.example.com/*
```

Yet some codepiece in this script 's relevant only to the site's homepage.

I tried to execute it only in the home page the following ways:

**1)**

```
if ( document.location === 'https://example.com' || document.location === 'https://www.example.com' ) {
    do stuff...
}
```

**2)**

```
if (window.location.href == window.location.origin) {
    Do stuff...
}
```

**3)**

```
if ( document.location == '/' ) {
    do stuff...
}
```

Yet these didn't help.

---

I thought of modifying the following code somehow:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('https://example.com' || window.location.href.indexOf('https://www.example.com') != -1) { // Do stuff...}
```

Maybe a modification with regex could ensure that anything else beyond the origin wouldn't count so the check will be: "if the document.location is only example.com, do stuff...".

Do you know a way?

Comment: You possibly mean `if (window.location.href.indexOf('https://example.com') !=-1 || window.location.href.indexOf('https://www.example.com') != -1) { // Do stuff...}` - you can also just test location.host

Comment: perhaps you're after `document.location.pathname == '/'`

Comment: @mplungjan thx. Why do we say !=-1 in JS and not just ===1? Why "not mistaken" instead just "right"?

Comment: indexOf returns -1 when not found. and it is 0 based so ===0 is also ok - it means it was found at position 0. but if you want a simpler test, you migh change to `indexOf("youtube")` and that will be some unknown number depending on www.youtube or m.youtube so testing for not found instead of found is always a Good Idea

Comment: Indeed @JaromandaX `if ( document.location.pathname == '/' ) {...} did the trick. Please publish an answer.